# SQL Server Distributed Partitioning Views how to add new node online

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, distributed, scaleout-hserver

We are using distributed partitioning views in SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Edition for scaling out our data across more than one servers. Now we faced to question how to add a new node (server) into the scale outed db servers system without sending the servers down, so our users will be able to use them during the process as well.

For example we have 4 servers with scaled out data. When we add the new empty server, the CHECKINGs for the partitioning columns should be  reorganized. But during the process the partitioning views are not working.

The High Availability, Always On or Failover Cluster approaches seem are not resolve the problems.

So my question is how to add new node online?